# Using a non-Computer Modern font in TeX

Tags: fonts

I installed the full version of TexLive 2015 on my new Mac OS/X El Capitan system but get font errors trying to typeset the following file:

```
\font\reffont=OpenSans-Regular at 20pt
\reffont
Fubar
\end
```

The full console session is below.  As you can see, the first hint of trouble is:

```
mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation O for OpenSans-Regular.
```

Same basic problem if I try `OpenSans`, `OpenSans-Bold`, `Helvetica`, or `helvetica`.

I thought of two potential gotchas, but the command line outputs below show that (a) the font is on my disk, and (b) I only have one installation of pdftex on my disk.

I also ran the TeX Live Utility and it says the package `opensans` is `Installed`.

So I'm stumped.  What does this mean:

```
Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
```

I hope you can help.  Thanks.

--

The OpenSans font is on my disk:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/opensans
$ ls -l
total 5144
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  224592 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  213292 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  221108 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-CondLight.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  210804 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-CondLightItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  222584 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  213420 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  212896 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  222412 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-Light.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  213128 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  217360 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  221328 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  212820 Aug 26  2011 OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf
```

I only have one installation of pdftex on my system:

```
$ sudo find / -name pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/universal-darwin/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex
```

Here is the console session:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./stub.tex
kpathsea: Running mktextfm OpenSans-Regular
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation O for OpenSans-Regular.
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input OpenSans-Regular
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf OpenSans-Regular

! I can't find file `OpenSans-Regular'.
<*> ...mag:=1; nonstopmode; input OpenSans-Regular

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...mag:=1; nonstopmode; input OpenSans-Regular

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: OpenSans-Regular.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input OpenSans-Regular' failed to make OpenSans-Regular.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

./stub.tex:1: Font \reffont=OpenSans-Regular at 20.0pt not loadable: Metric (TF
M) file not found.
l.1 \font\reffont=OpenSans-Regular at 20pt

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on stub.log.
```

Comment: Apparently you try to use a `TrueType` or `OpenType` font. This does not work with `pdflatex`. Try `xetex` or `luatex`

Comment: To load a system font in `xetex` you have to put it in quotes as in `\font\reffont="OpenSans-Regular" at 20pt`.  For `luatex` you additionally need `\input luaotfload.sty`.

Comment: @Iron Pillow: Do you try to compile with `plain` pdftex, not `pdflatex`?

Comment: Great and helpful comments -- thanks.  @Bernard, I was using `pdftex`, which implements a version of plain TeX.

Comment: to use `pdftex` on a file with non-cm fonts, a `.tfm` file must be available for each.  your installation list doesn't show any `.tfm` files/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use TrueType fonts (a.k.a. system fonts) in TeX you have to use one of the new engines `xetex` or `luatex`.  The `luatex` engine doesn't support loading of system fonts right away, but it has to be enabled first on the Lua level, which is done by `luaotfload.sty`.

To load a system font you have to put its name in quotes.  The name is the one displayed in FontBook on Mac OS X or the one after the path in the output of `fc-list` under GNU/Linux.

```
\ifdefined\directlua
  \input luaotfload.sty
\fi
\font\reffont="Open Sans" at 20pt
\reffont Hello from Open Sans!
\bye
```

> [image]

Through Bernard's answer I found out, that there exists a Type1 version of OpenSans which is usable within `pdftex`.  Here is a sample, which produces the same output as above.

```
\font\reffont=OpenSans-Regular-ot1 at 20pt
\reffont Hello from Open Sans!
\bye
```

There is currently some sort of trade-off between the `pdftex` and the `xe/luatex` solution.  The engines `xetex` and `luatex` make font feature selection much easier, as all features are incorporated in a single file.  Selecting features in `pdftex` requires loading another font file, but `pdftex` offers a much better stability and is a lot faster!

Comment: Some puzzling behavior here.  Typesetting the file above with luatex works fine.  With XeTeX, it fails -- I think the explanation is that `Open Sans` does not appear in FontBook.  (That may be fodder for a separate question.) But XeTeX typesetting works for fonts that do appear in FontBook.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Open Sans can also be used from within LaTeX: load the [`opensans`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/opensans) package and either use the `\fosfamily` switch or via the `defaultsans` or `default` package options.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{opensans}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}%

\fosfamily
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]